# Cannot find module 'read' when using ionic start

Tags: node.js, npm, ionic-framework

Trying to get started with ionic and am not able start an app.

When I try `ionic start myApp blank` it gives the above error, `cannot find module 'read'`.

```
aarmora@Breeze:/home/sites$ ionic start taskApp blank

Error: Cannot find module 'read'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:326:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:277:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:354:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/prompt/lib/prompt.js:12:12)
    at Module._compile (module.js:410:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:417:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:344:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:301:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:354:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)

Cannot find module 'read' (CLI v1.7.14)

Your system information:

Cordova CLI: Not installed
Gulp version:  CLI version 3.9.0
Gulp local:  
Ionic CLI Version: 1.7.14
Ionic App Lib Version: 0.7.0
OS: Distributor ID: Ubuntu Description: Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS 
Node Version: v4.3.0
```

When I try to install this package, it looks like it's already installed.

```
aarmora@Breeze:/home/sites$ sudo npm install -g read
read@1.0.7 /usr/lib/node_modules/read
└── mute-stream@0.0.5
```

I've uninstalled node, cordova, ionic and reinstalled all of them but it yields the same.

Any ideas?

Comment: try not to install it globally: `npm install read`

Comment: @topheman Thanks for the suggestion!  I did try this and it gave the same thing.  =/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is clearly a problem with the installation of ionic. Since you've stated that you've already tried to reinstall ionic and it didn't work, here are two options:

1) Reinstallation with a clean cache

```
npm cache clean
npm uninstall ionic -g
npm install ionic -g
```

2) If the previous one didn't work, let's get a little more hacky

```
cd /usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic
npm install read
```

For both options, according to your machine config, you might have to `sudo`.

Comment: I think this worked.  It's not giving me the read error anymore but I'm currently installing lots of other modules the same way.  Is that what I should expect?

Comment: are you on npm3 ? run `npm --version` it is known to have bugs with dedupe dependencies

Comment: 2.4.12.  How do I upgrade?

Comment: I've now installed json-stringify-safe, qs, bl, hawk, aws-sign2, http-signature this way.

Comment: You should report the problem on the issue tracker of ionic - in the mean time, so that you could make your project work, you might have to use the workaround I gave you ... and maybe mention it (some people might have the same problem as you have)